# Loop Count 'forever' does not run test indefinitely

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

JMeter version - 2.12
I am using JMeter with following thread group configuration -

Number of Threads - 2
Ramp-Up period - 0
Loop Count - Forever checkbox checked

I was expecting tests to run indefinitely since I checked Loop Count 'Forever' checkbox but it stops after 2 thread. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can you post your testplan? Have you checked the option 'Stop Test' on error?

Comment: I have not selected 'Stop Test' option in the wake of errors. Test plan is available here - https://gist.github.com/tarun3kumar/a01a1908b8d6f3791540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your test plan. You have a `loop controller` which has been set to run only once under the thread group. If you want the test to run indefinitely  remove this loop controller.

Answer (score -1):

There could be various reasons:

1. Have a check on test plan how it has been configured
2. have a check for resources you are connecting to, in case it is throwing any error
3. check the error console/jmeter.log file to exactly check what is happening here.

Please ensure to collect as much info as possible as it helps the community as well :)

Comment: Here is the test plan I am using -
https://gist.github.com/tarun3kumar/a01a1908b8d6f3791540

don't see any explicit error.